# Is the MLE of a statistic always defined?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, inference

My current understanding is that the MLE of a statistic is the mode of its posterior pdf under a uniform prior. The problem with this is that I don't think the posterior pdf needs to exist. The posterior cdf could be non-differentiable at points. In such circumstances is the MLE undefined or is there a more general definition of the MLE?

Here is an example of a situation in which I think you get a non-differential posterior cdf:
Let $C$ be a random variable that represents a coin flip. $C = 1$ with probability $p$ (the coin is biased) and $C = 0$ with probability $(1 - p)$. Let's say you flip the coin $N$ times and get a sequence of 1s and 0s: $x_1, x_2, ... x_N$. Given this sequence, what is the MLE of the variance $v$ of $C$?

Using the invariance property of the MLE, it should just be $\hat{v} = \hat{p}(1 - \hat{p})$ where $\hat{p} = \frac{1}{N} \sum x_i$ is the MLE of $p$.

Now, I'll try to do this calculation the longer way by attempting to calculate the posterior distribution of $v$.

The posterior distribution of $p$ given a uniform prior is:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\alpha}x^k (1 - x)^{n - k}$$
where $\alpha = \int_0^1 x^k (1 - x)^{n - k} dx$. The posterior cdf of $v = p(1 - p)$ can be computed as follows:
$$Pr(v < x) = Pr(p(1 - p) < x) = Pr(|p - 1/2| > \sqrt{1/4 - x})$$
$$= 1 - \frac{1}{\alpha} \int_{1/2 - \sqrt{1/4 - x}}^{1/2 + \sqrt{1/4 - x}} t^k (1 - t)^{n - k} dt$$
Here's a graph of the posterior cdf of $v$:

[image: posterior cdf of $v} with uniform prior]

Note that the derivative of $1/2 + \sqrt{1/4 - x} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1/4 - x}}$ is not defined at $x = 1/4$ so the derivative of $Pr(v < x)$ is not defined there as as well. In fact, the pdf grows to infinity as $x$ approaches 1/4. Since the pdf doesn't seem to have a maximum, why is $\hat{v} = \hat{p}(1 - \hat{p})$?

What mistake am I making? Is there a more general definition of the MLE that I am not aware of?

Comment: 1) A maximum likelihood estimator is of a parameter, not a statistic.  A statistic is a function of the data.  2)  The MLE has nothing to do with posterior distributions, which are Bayesian.  It is the value of the parameter that maximizes the likelihood function.

Comment: The existence of modes, and maxima in general, does not require differentiability.  You go astray after you identify $f.$ An easy way to maximize it is to check for critical points (places where it's either *not differentiable* or has zero derivative) of the log of $f.$  The CDF is irrelevant.  After all, a basic probability axiom guarantees every CDF has a supremum equal to $1.$ Still, MLEs don't always exist.  Consider the MLE of the variance of a Normal$(\mu,\sigma)$ distribution based on a single observation.

Comment: Answering the possibly intended question of whether the MLE of a *parameter* must always exist: no. The classical example is logistic regression on linearly separable data: you can always get a higher (log-)likelihood by pushing the linear predictor towards $\pm \infty$ (probabilities of 0/1), but since you can never actually get to infinity, the maximum is not attained. Continuity of the likelihood + compactness of the parameter space should ensure existence of an MLE (but not uniquness). See https://doi.org/10.1093/aje/kwx299 for recent discussion of the logistic + separable data case in epi